# Makefile - linker input file unused because linking not done

Tags: c++, linux, gcc, makefile

I have a problem with my Makefile that won't work with an error I don't understand.

Here is the error :

```
g++ -ISFML/include -c src/gameManager/component.cpp -o obj/Component.o -lsfml-graphics -lsfml-window -lsfml-system -lsfml-main
g++ -ISFML/include -c src/gameManager/gameManager.cpp -o obj/GameManager.o -g obj/Component.o -lsfml-graphics -lsfml-window -lsfml-system -lsfml-main
g++: warning: obj/Component.o: linker input file unused because linking not done
g++ -ISFML/include -c src/main.cpp -o obj/main.o obj/GameManager.o
g++: warning: obj/GameManager.o: linker input file unused because linking not done
g++ -LSFML/lib -o bin/main.exe -g obj/main.o obj/GameManager.o -lsfml-graphics -lsfml-window -lsfml-system -lsfml-main
/usr/bin/ld : ne peut trouver -lsfml-graphics
/usr/bin/ld : ne peut trouver -lsfml-window
/usr/bin/ld : ne peut trouver -lsfml-system
/usr/bin/ld : ne peut trouver -lsfml-main
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile:14: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 1
```

And here is the Makefile :

```
INCLUDE = -ISFML/include
LIB = -LSFML/lib
LINK_SFML = -lsfml-graphics -lsfml-window -lsfml-system -lsfml-main

ifeq ($(OS),Windows_NT)
    LINKER_FLAGS = -lmingw32 $(LINK_SFML)
else
    LINKER_FLAGS = $(LINK_SFML)
endif

all : GameManager.o
    g++ $(INCLUDE) -c src/main.cpp -o obj/main.o obj/GameManager.o
    g++ $(LIB) -o bin/main.exe -g obj/main.o obj/GameManager.o $(LINKER_FLAGS)

GameManager.o : Component.o
    g++ $(INCLUDE) -c src/gameManager/gameManager.cpp -o obj/GameManager.o -g obj/Component.o $(LINKER_FLAGS)

Component.o :
    g++ $(INCLUDE) -c src/gameManager/component.cpp -o obj/Component.o $(LINKER_FLAGS)
```

note : it works on W10 but doesn't on Ubuntu Linux.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Do you have SFML installed on the machine you are using? BTW, the warning on an unused linker file has nothing to do with the linkage failure. It's a reminder that there is no need to pass linker flags to `g++` when you compile with `-c` (which means: don't do linking).

Comment: The `-c` flag tells `g++` to create object file, it't not linking. And when compiling into object files, other object files can't be used as input.

Comment: Regarding the `linker input file unused` message, you're passing `$(LINKER_FLAGS)` to the compiler event though you specify `-c` which means 'compile only -- do not link'.

Comment: According to your linker command `g++ -LSFML/lib ...-lsfml-graphics ...`, the library `libsfml-graphics` should be either in `SFML/lib` or in any of the system library directories. Where is the library on your Linux system? Please [edit] your question to add information, don't use comments to answer.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your build configuration is not platform-independent and you don't have `sfml` library installed on your Ubuntu.

To solve this, install `sfml` by the following command:

```sh
sudo apt install libsfml-dev
```

Now remove `-lsfml-main` from `LINK_SFML` variable as it is only for Windows. Then add `-lsfml-main` to `LINKER_FLAGS` if platform is Windows like this:

```
ifeq ($(OS),Windows_NT)
    LINKER_FLAGS = -lmingw32 -lsfml-main $(LINK_SFML)
else
    LINKER_FLAGS = $(LINK_SFML)
endif
```

Your code should now compile, the warning will still appear. To remove the warning, remove linker options from compilation commands. Also, on Linux, libraries and headers are usually available in system directories. So you don't need the `LIB` and `INCLUDE` variable. So, instead of this:

```
INCLUDE = -ISFML/include
LIB = -LSFML/lib
```

Use this:

```
ifeq ($(OS),Windows_NT)
    INCLUDE = -ISFML/include
    LIB = -LSFML/lib
endif
```

Your `Makefile` should work correctly now.